# How to include namespace in another file of another project in vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a c++ project in visual studio.
In the source file, I have created a namespace there and a class inside it.
Now I have added another project to the same solution.
In the new project I am trying to use the previously declared namespace.
It is not allowing me to do that.
It throws a compiler error saying "The name must be a namespace name".
How to use it?

Answer (score 1):

> In the source file, I have created a namespace there and a class
>   inside it.

You should do this in the header file (`.h` or `.hpp`) not in the source file(`.cpp`). Then in the other project you can include that header file using:

```
#include "path_of_the_header/xxx.h" // e.g #include "../../include/proj1/xx.h"
```

In this way, the other project will be able to see the namespace and the class inside it.

Comment: What do you mean Source of the header. Can you show me an example?

Comment: "Source of the header" I did not say that? what is not clear?

Comment: #include "source_of_the_header/xxx.h"

What is source of header here?

Comment: Oh sorry! path of the header

Comment: Inside MyHeader.h I have written

namespace My{}

Now in another project I am trying to do this

#inlcude "MyHeader.h"
This is not allowed as well

Comment: OK and did you include it where you use it ?

Comment: I am trying to use it in the new project only and that is where I am trying to do this  #inlcude "MyHeader.h"

Answer (score -1):

in your header file:

```
#ifndef _XXX_H_
#define _XXX_H_
```

You typically #include the header where you will be using the methods.

Comment: Include guards should go inside the header file completely.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote, wasn't it? :)

Comment: @PedroG.Dias No, you propose to put the `#ifndef _XXX_H_` before including the header file, this statement should go inside the header file.

Comment: Firstly, your question doesn't address the (badly described) issue. Secondly, you define macros that are reserved, which you shouldn't. Thirdly, the whole triple of `#ifdef`, `#define` and `#endif` should go into the header file.

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer :) Thanks for correcting me